# Python socket programming How to make file array to json format

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, sockets

I want to print my created file to console. But my loop goes infinitly. How can i read all my file names to one array.

```
from socket import *
import os
import math
serverPort = 12000

# Create a UDP socket
serverSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM)
content_name = 'py'
filename = content_name+'.txt'
c = os.path.getsize(filename)
#print(c)
CHUNK_SIZE = math.ceil(math.ceil(c)/5)
#print(CHUNK_SIZE)
while 1:
 index = 1
 with open(filename, 'rb') as infile:
     chunk = infile.read(int(CHUNK_SIZE))
     while chunk:
         chunkname = content_name+'_'+str(index)
         #print("chunk name is: " + chunkname + "\n")
         with open(chunkname,'wb+') as chunk_file:
             chunk_file.write(chunk)
         index += 1
         chunk = infile.read(int(CHUNK_SIZE))
chunk_file.close()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your loop "While 1" will run infinitely, and there is no way to break out of this loop. In python, 1 is a truthy value, which means it evaluates to true in this situation, so the loop is infinite. Hope this helps

Comment: Yes. i recognized it and i remove it. But still i cant print those created files as a json format. i got too many errors when i try to dumps and loads json functions. Any advice ?